# Adding SubView to window close the app in ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, window, subview

I have ipad application in which i want to add splitViewController once LoginViewController is loaded and user press sign in button then the following notification works,but what happens by adding following code it close the app and again open then it shows.

```
 -(void)actionNotificationData:(NSNotification *)notification {

 [self.loginViewController removeFromSuperview];


UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
if (!window) 
    window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
[[[window subviews] objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:splitViewController];  

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 [self.loginViewController removeFromSuperview];
```

`removeFromSuperview` is expecting a `UIView's` subclass and you are passing a `UIViewController`.

Comment: so how to solve this also splitViewController which i am adding is also UIViewController any idea how to fix this

Comment: You need to replace the rootViewController from your window object. Like: `window.rootViewController = splitViewController`. I am assuming you are aiming for iOS 4.0+.

Comment: windwo.rootViewController=splitViewController places in portrait and my app view is landscape how to fix it and also i think we should remove loginView controller first and then add it

Comment: @user2240329 you asked a question about how to replace a rootViewController by another. If you are having issues with portrait and landscape, make another question. `i think we should remove loginView controller first and then add it`, well read the documentation about the `rootViewController`and you will change your opinion.